# Save form data to multi-value field on MongoDB using Play2.2.2

Tags: forms, mongodb, playframework, mongo-jackson-mapper

I'm experimenting with play (v2.2.2), and I have it connected to MongoDB (v2.4.6) using jackson.

I have a `models.Role` class with the following attributes:

```
@Id
@ObjectId
public String id;

public String name;
public ArrayList<String> permissions;
```

On the template (`roles.scala.html`), I can easily get the list of permissions to be printed on the HTML, but when I try to add a new role passing a single permission as a string in the form as an `@InputText` field, it does not get recorded in MongoDB. I suppose that it is because play/scala is trying to assign a simple `String` to an `ArrayList<String>`.

Any ideas on the propper approach? Maybe I should do some logic on the `create()` method under Role class?